# How to Pay Yourself a Salary in a Single Member S-Corp with Inconsistent Income

Tags: united-states, salary, s-corporation

It seems a requirement of a single-member S-Corp is to pay one's self a "salary" - suggesting a weekly or bi-weekly payment that amounts to a pre-determined figure at year's end - but in a single person company, business can easily ebb and flow. What if the business makes no revenue for 2-3 months? What if you expect to pay yourself $50k for the year, but the business only makes $40k total?

Given all of the unknowns, how can the payment of a "normal salary" be a requirement? And if it's not, what is the actual requirement?

Comment: Did your S-Corp generate any income at all? From what you've described so far it sounds like you're only starting, maybe the issue is moot because there was no actual business activity? The reasonable salary comes into play only if there's net income, otherwise no-one cares that you don't pay yourself (this is exactly the opposite from C-Corps - in S-Corps salaries increase taxes, in C-Corp they reduce them).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ...suggesting a weekly or bi-weekly payment that amounts to a pre-determined figure at year's end...

**There is no rule that a salary be paid regularly.**

As a single S-Corp owner, I had some years where I paid myself once on Dec 31 with the entire year's salary. One of those years consisted of taking draws throughout the year, and my accountant converted them to either salary or distributions on Dec 31. That year my salary check netted zero and I still had to write a check for the payroll and withholding taxes due in the beginning of January, so make sure to prepare for that if you go this route (of taking uncategorized draws throughout the year).

I also had some years where I took salary monthly, but skipped some months when cash flow was low.

The "reasonable" rule for salary and S-Corps only applies to the total year's W2 amount, not the frequency in which it's paid.

Comment: Thanks for this. Did you also just pay FUTA taxes once, in that year that you paid yourself once on Dec 31?

Comment: @number41 yes, I paid both FUTA and SUTA. You get a 5.4% credit from SUTA though, so the effective FUTA rate is only 0.6% on $7K, or just $42 per employee per year.

Comment: thanks, yes I noticed that, I’m in NJ though and can’t seem to find anything about the SUTA there. How did you find out how to pay your state SUTA?

Comment: @number41 Here's the [website for NJ SUTA](https://www.nj.gov/labor/ea/employer-services/rate-info/).

Comment: Thanks so much!

Comment: This answer is correct at the high level, but there are some pitfalls in the details. Need to remember that payroll reporting is quarterly based, so you cannot easily backdate payments without amending payroll forms, and the withholding have to be remitted within a certain period of time, which again affects how easily you can go back in time. So if you just pay salary once a year on Dec. 31st - that's not a problem, but if you made payments throughout a year - you may not be able to wait till year end to decide on how to characterize them.

Comment: @littleadv I agree, and I even considered removing those sentences to avoid confusion. The important thing here is that the salary payments were never backdated, as only 1 existed on Dec 31. In the years where I took salary on a monthly basis, but only sometimes, I paid the taxes monthly too.

Comment: Hi @TTT, if you pay yourself once at the end of the year, and when you pay the employer half of the FICA taxes, what do you do when you personally have already reached the ~$143k threshold (from another job) at which you no longer owe further OASDI? Do you simply stop paying it as the employer as well, or do you as the employer have to pay to some other threshold perhaps?

Comment: @number41 that might be a good new question (if it hasn't been asked already- I haven't checked). I think the answer is that all employers withhold FICA as if their employees only work for them. (In other words, even if the employer knows their employees have other jobs, it still doesn't matter.) This means the *employer* portion of FICA may be overpaid and there is no reclaiming that. On the employee side, if you overpaid SS then you can reclaim it as a tax credit when you file your taxes.